# the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, http

When I try to call with `this.http.get` and `@GetMapping` I am able to send the call to spring controller,

When I try to change from `this.http.get` to `this.http.post` and from  `@GetMapping` to  `@PostMapping` I am not able to call the spring controller `/api/v1/basicauth` method.

As I am having username and password I want to use `PostMapping` only

My code as below:-

**Angular**

```
var formData: any = new FormData();
formData.append("userName", username);
formData.append("password", password);

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('username', username);
params = params.append('password', password);
return this.http.post<any>('/api/v1/basicauth', { formData }).pipe(map((res) => {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}));
```

**Spring boot:-**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/basicauth")
public AuthenticationBean helloWorldBean(@RequestBody UserDetails user) {
log.info("Start helloWorldBean method");
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
    public class UserDetails {

        private int userId;
        private String userName;
        private String password;
   }
```

Comment: how about trying "{username, password}" instead of "{formData}" as "body" parameter?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I am able to call to spring controller by using body parameter with this.http.get

Comment: And what happen if you try do to the same with "this.http.post"?

Comment: You rest is implemented for GET than why are you sending post from angular ?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I am not able to call using `this.http.post`

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I have changed my rest with post and I am trying to call from `this.http.post` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `FormData (Angular)` as your controller is accepting `@RequestBody`

your `formData` should be something like

```
var formData = {"username": username, "password": password};
```

Rest will deserilize automatically it to `UserDetails` class

Answer (score 1):

**Client side**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>('/api/v1/basicauth', { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // eg.
                // localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                return user;
            }));
```

Example from: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

**Server side**

You are retrieving paramaters with @RequestParam, which means you're expeting parametes as `http://host:8080/api/auth?password=abc&...`.

Please check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Comment: I want to pass the username and password as an json object, I am able to recieve the uname and pwd individually, I want to recieve as a object in java even

Comment: How are you receiving those two on server side? ... and I think you're miss-using pipe and also post & get(? @GetMapping) methods on client and server.

Comment: @RequestParam(name = "username") String username,@RequestParam(name = "password") String password

Comment: @Codelover updated answer & I think this isn't the right way. Learn more about it on: [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param).

Comment: I will check that link, but I am saying currnetly I am using as parameters as I am not able to send as a object.I have updated with the correct code

Comment: @Codelover with current setup, server is looking at the end of requests "link" for parameters. Under Server side part of answer I linked you the example, which is closest to your  problem.